# Как передать структуру sockaddr_in в функцию? с++

Tags: c++, функции, объявление

```
sockaddr_in address[4],from,fromCommand;
 for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
 {
address[i].sin_family = AF_INET;
address[i].sin_addr.s_addr = INADDR_ANY;
address[i].sin_port = htons(12340+i);
```

функция:

```
void priempackets(struct sock sockets[],int maximum_packet_size,
struct sockaddr_in from,address[],
int line,schetline, struct WAVHEADER wavhead)
```

ругается на 2рую строчку (struct sockaddr_in from,address[],)и ошибка [BCC32 Error] Unit1.cpp(27): E2303 Type name expected
вот что передаю:

```
_beginthread( priempackets, 0, sockets,maximum_packet_size,from,address,
line,schetline,wavhead);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Нельзя задавать список параметров, не указывая тип каждого из параметров в списке. У вас в объявлении функции написано

```
void priempackets(struct sock sockets[],int maximum_packet_size,
struct sockaddr_in from,address[],
                   ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^         
int line,schetline, struct WAVHEADER wavhead)
```

То есть следуют друг за другом два идентификатора без указания типа у каждого отдельного идентификатора.

Comment: ок, спс. Просто тот пример, который я нашёл в интернете по передачи структуры в функцию был только с одним аргументом.